# Amazon S3, jgit Push a really large file

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi, I am using Amazon S3 as my git repository and I have this huge file (Android source code) that is about 15G.  Using Jgit to push, I always get this out heap run out of memory error.

I am not creating an application to upload this big file. Is there anyway way to use jgit for multiple parts upload?

Is there anyway to get around this? Would this work: I am thinking that we could create the git files locally and then using s3cmd to upload to a folder in Amazon S3?

Thanks,

```
hbu@hbusz1:/mnt/data/user/ben/source$ jgit push s3 android-4.4
Counting objects:       298258
Finding sources:        100% (298258/298258)
Getting sizes:          100% (298257/298257) 
Compressing objects:     99% (7329769/7329782)
Put pack-e647569..pack: 0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at     org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.UnpackedObject.open(UnpackedObject.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectory.openLooseObject(ObjectDirectory.java:436)
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectory.openLooseFromSelfOrAlternate(ObjectDirectory.java:393)
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectory.openObject(ObjectDirectory.java:375)
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.WindowCursor.open(WindowCursor.java:145)
at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectReader.open(ObjectReader.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.pack.PackWriter.buffer(PackWriter.java:1626)
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.pack.DeltaWindow.buffer(DeltaWindow.java:408)
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.pack.DeltaWindow.delta(DeltaWindow.java:293)
```

Answer (score 0):

If, by any chance, you keep large binary files that frequently change it might be possible that it's the git issue with calculating deltas of these files.

I would try adding .gitattributes on the top folder with example contents:

`*.dat -delta`

where .dat is extension of the binaries